# Jquery Tab with radio button -> empty $_POST

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, radio-button

I would like using [JqueryUI tab](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) with radio button.
Tab selection working well, but radio button selection don't work. Radio button still empty in my $_POST

Here is the source code :

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#tabs-1">
        <label for="choice1">Nunc tincidunt</label>    
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="choice1" id="choice1" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tabs-2">
        <label for="choice2">Protor lorem</label>
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="choice2" id="choice2" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
    My content 1
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    My content 2
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Where is my mistake ?